# Why does phpinfo() show version 5.5.9 but php -v show version 7.0

Tags: ubuntu, php

I am running ubuntu on vagrant box and am successfully running and developing LAMP applications.

BACKGROUND: I am trying to install laravel with composer and getting "the requested PHP extension `mbstring` is missing from your system".

My `/etc/php` directory contains two directories inside of it: 7.0 and 7.1

Yet when I run a file with `phpinfo()`, it tells me I'm running `PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20`

But executing `php -v`says I'm running version 7.0.14:

```
root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/var/www/homebase/src# php -v
PHP 7.0.14-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.14-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

QUESTION: Why am I seeing the discrepancy?

Comment: These are two `php`s. One is official Ubuntu release (`5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20`), one is installed from other source (`7.0.14-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+1`). So the output will depend on which `php` executable you are running.

Comment: The problem is that composer is telling me for example: "laravel/framework v5.1.12 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system."  The php 5 has mbstring, but composer being run from the command line must see 7.0 and must not think PHP has it?  How do I handle that?

Comment: You have to find the correct PHP executable, matching the one used by your web server.  If you don't have a clue where it is, you could try `find /usr -name php` to find it.

Comment: Whats the output of `type -a php`?

Comment: I was using WAMPServer. http://blog.astemplates.com/change-php-version-wamp/ helped me.

Answer (score 1):

`phpinfo()` shows the version of the Apache PHP module, which is provided by `libapache2-mod-php`. You need to upgrade that (or install one of the specific versions such as `libapache2-mod-php7.1`).

Answer (score 1):

> Why am I seeing the discrepancy?

at compile (`make`) time - PHP's source configuration triggers multiple SAPI's to be built. e.g `php-cli`, `php-cgi`, `php-debug` and others depending on your compiletime configuration.
Note: you might not be able to access the compile time config options with the the debian or ubuntu packaged version of PHP as the package maintainers had - in the past (not sure if it still applies) - made changes which suppress the printing of the compile time configurations (using `php-config`), see: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-server-bugs/2010-April/034631.html

Otherwise, each SAPI is a binary executable which provides a point of interaction for anything wanting to run PHP code on the PHP interpreter. 
During the `make install` or `checkinstall --pkgname=php-self-compiled` or the package configuration these SAPI will be placed at different locations on your filesystem.
The cli SAPI - which you get when you run `php -v`, will likely be placed somewhere like `/bin/php` or `/usr/bin/php` and the cgi SAPI will be started as a daemon (as part of the webserving subsystem) at boot via an init script or systemd.
So a webserver that wanted to run a PHP script will use a - pre-launched instance of a `php-cgi` SAPI and pass it a script to be run. This SAPI will have its own run-time configuration (viewable by a launching your server with `strace`.  )
If you run `php` from the command line you will get a different SAPI, again, possibly with its own run time configuration, again, this can be confirmed with `strace php -v`.

Each SAPI - usually - originates from the same compilation operation and thus share many compile time configurations (like which extensions to add and whether they should be compiled static or linked at run time) as well as version number etc.
This is why you get behaviours when you try to probe PHP's configuration that are similar enough to make you think they are the same program, but yet still are inconsistent in some ways, they are separate programs that share alot of the same objects underneath the hood, but have different configurations and are designed to serve different environments, for example, when PHP-cli (which is what composer runs) prints error messages, it expects they will be printed to the terminal, so it prints plain text, when the `php-fpm` , or `php-cgi` prints that same error it will wrap it in HTML, because it assumes its being interacted with by some web related process. php-debug again will expect to be interfaced with differently, receive data connections on port 9000 etc...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect (I don't have an Ubuntu box to check) that the problem is related to the difference between php-cgi and the straight php used by the command line. It looks like Ubuntu uses phpX-cgi when you install the LAMP stack. The cgi version uses a php.ini file and this can further complicate matters as it will change the path to the cwd.